# VIC-20 vs. VC20 (or VC-20)

Tags: vic-20

My first computer was a VC20. Was it just renamed (for the German market?) as a VolksComputer?

[image: original VC20 box]

(I am a Finn and the VC was bought in Finland). Or were there any actual differences to VIC-20?

Comment: Out of interest, was all the documentation that came with it in German or in Finnish?

Comment: I am really sorry for not visiting here enough! Thanks to the guy / gal who edited my question as well. @hippietrail as for the language, I can't remember for sure. I have a feeling it may have come with a German original manual and a photocopied version of an English VIC-20 one (probabaly, as not only me, but also my parents were too good in German).

Comment: I put the photo in. I misread your question and thought you were wondering if VC-20 stood for "VolksComputer". I had no idea it was written all over the box and everything until I Googled it. So I put a pic in just in case anyone else was as dumb as me. But yes I also wondered if the VC-20 name was used only in German markets and markets that sourced from Germany, or if it was used in a few countries regardless of language.

Comment: @hippietrail So you both fixed my question & answered it!!! Thank you. Sorry, I don't have access to / knowledge of the docs (living in Japan nowadays). But, as you also seem to have interest: "I" (or practically my dad, I guess I was abt 7 at the time) bought it from "Bebek" which probably doesn't exist anymore but when existed was a miniature version of Radioshack (I mean miniature version of what RS was in the 80's!!!).

Comment: @hippietrail Sorry! Just Googled. Bebek is alive, kicking, and still like they were 40 years ago!!! Go to http://bebek.fi/kauppa/index2.php and you see capacitors, diodes and stuff!! But, in Finland, despite being the country of Linux and Slush, I am worried if they have enough customers.

Answer (score 18):

> VIC-20 vs VC20 (or VC-20)

In all original documents only VC20. Often stylised with the C as the commodore logo "C=". The intended naming was always *Commodore<space>VC20*, like written on the machine as well (*1).

> My 1st computer was a VC20. Anone knows if it was just renamed (for German market?) as a VolksComputer?

The most told story is that VIC *can* be pronounced in German close to 'Fick' which would be 'a fuck'. So they decided to change it. But despite searching since back then, I couldn't find any reliable source to prove it. Also, I know noone who would mix this up, not even an adolescent trying really hard. More important here, German uses, unlike English, a lot of inflections so a remote similarity of the base word will not transform as well in real usage. So using 'Fick' in German isn't as universal and simple as in (US) English. 'Fick Computer' for example simply doesn't make any sense.

A supporting argument often made is that it would be pronounced that way in some regions like Bavaria. Being from Bavaria, I can not validate this. While we do pronounce *some* words spelled with 'V' different than lets say northerners, it's still different from the F sound in most cases all over Germany.

So in my opinion it's an urban myth made up afterwards - don't we all 'know' how puritan, bigot and outright weird Americans are when it comes to bodily functions? That's a great base for a myth to work with :)

A more believable story goes that they simply came up with the idea to sell it as a computer for everyone. Volkscomputer has a great ring to German ears. Just compare Volkswagen, Volksfest, Volkshochschule, Volkslied, Volksstadion and many other well known names starting with Volk*. Using that name was a once in a life time chance to place the computer right in everyone's mind as established and positive.

How hard Commodore tried to position them self close to Volkswagen shows this add for a programming challenge in 1982 (*2):

[image]

While not able to right out claim similarity to Volkswagen they simply did a challenge for VC20 programmers with a VW convertible as price, so they could put it in their add. This add was run for several month not only in next to every computer magazine but as well non computer papers.

Pure genius. It may have been the greatest branding in that decade (at least). Whoever made it should be named #1 post war advertizer.

At that point it's also noteworthy that it was neither advertized nor sold as Volkscomputer 20 which would be the case if VC20 is an abbrevation, but as [VC20 - Volkscomputer](https://www.computermuseum-ebenthal.at/commodore-vc-20/) on packageing, [manuals](https://www.mingos-commodorepage.com/sammlung/lektuere_detail.php?id=58) and [add on packaging](https://www.c64-wiki.de/wiki/Datei:VC20_Schreibmaschinenkurs_OVP.jpg) or hyphenated as ["Volks-Computer"](https://retroport.de/retro-kult-quelle-katalog/). Booktiltes were like *Lerne Basic mit dem Volkscomputer VC20*.

"Volkscomputer" was as well used with the C64, at least early on. After all, why giving up such a great label?

> Or were there were any actual differences to VIC-20?

No, or more correct, none beside being a PAL machine.

---

*1 - Similar the C64 was never called so in original documentation, but always *Commodore<space>64* - as well like written on the machine itself.

*2 - Taken from the pages of [Werner Kracht](http://www.wernerkracht.com/TextContent/Sequencer%20Story.htm), who did win the VW with a music sequencer - and sold it right the next day to buy a professional tape deck for recording.

Comment: Massive digression, but what other sorts of high school could there possibly be? Or does that just mean a state-run school rather than a private one?

Comment: @Tommy are you talking about Volkshochschule? It might be best translated as Peoples-University. It's one of the great left overs of the workers and citizens enlightenment of the 19th century. The basic idea is about life long learning (way before it was a business hype). In Germany these are usually city run, but there isn't a fixed curriculum or a degree to earn, but a huge mixture of lectures, courses, seminars, speeches and whatsoever. In Munch for example about 20,000 per year. The city just supports space and organization, will all teaching is on a peer to peer base

Comment: @Tommy There's a [wiki-entry about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_high_school) - although, it really gives only a very rough explanation.

Comment: [which](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=wich) and [abbreviation](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=abrevation)

Comment: @Tommy, also note that a German Hochschule is a university, not an American High School.

Comment: Yes, I think I've learnt that die Volkshochschule is similar to the UK's Open University but much broader in scope. I don't know what a broad equivalent would be in the US; I strongly suspect there isn't one.

Comment: @Tommy Interesting. I always thought Open University is more like a Fernuniversität. Curriculum wise like any other, except learning is (mostly) remote. Volkshochschule isn'T like that, it's complete free form. It may offer a few formal courses, but usually it's anything goes. Like, for example setting up a C64 repair workshop :)

Comment: Does "all original documents" include internal documents to Commodore Germany? I'm assuming it does not mean the actual original documents which were presumably in English. Anyway *why* go to all the trouble of changing the name for an abbreviation only ever hinted at by on ad? I know movies and books all get their names changed for the German market but how common is this for computers?

Comment: @hippietrail It was the 80s, when movies still got their name changed to German - nowadays hey make up fake English, if at all :( All got to be translated anyway. While one may be able to sell a computer with English only documentation only, it wouldn't really a benefit. Not to mention that it automatic includes Swiss and Austrian market. Renaming isn't just a German thing. Of course Volkscomputer was as well used in manuals. Eventually more often than VIC was spelled out in English ones.

Comment: @hippietrail  Last and most important, Germany was already at PET times Commodore's top market (not to mention that they stayed profitable until the very end. Whole point was IMHO to build an image on par with Volkswagen. And it worked. The VC20 sold in DACH like sliced bread.

Comment: Schokolade zum Frühstück 2001 Bridget Jones' Diary. The '80s lasted much longer over there (-; But *why* change it from an inoffensive word to an inoffensive abbreviation that was never official? This is nothing more than a theory without precedent. Are none of the Commodore officials of the day still alive? Have not books been written and interviews made? Why did they not go ahead with Volkscomputer besides the solitary ad? What is the theory for that?

Comment: @hippietrail Of course you might always find an example (btw, it was _"Bridget Jones – Schokolade zum Frühstück"_ with Bridget Jones in large letters and the German part as subtitle). Example: Last weeks top 5 cinema charts: 1. Bad Boys for Life; 2. Nightlife; 3. Sonic the Hedgehog; 4. Knives Out; 5. 1917. All English titles, of these only Knives Out got a German subtitle. So no, they do not put any effort into Titles anymore. But hey, it's their money that sinks if customer don't get it.

Comment: @hippietrail What do you mean with 'that was never official'? Ho much more official can it be, than being written on every add, every package and every [manual](https://www.mingos-commodorepage.com/sammlung/lektuere_detail.php?id=58) ?

Comment: They wrote the reason for the name change on every package and every manual?

Comment: @hippietrail Now you lost me. They wrote 'Volkscomputer' on everything - or what are you talking about?

Comment: Oops apologies are warranted. I missed that it was actually called "VolksComputer". I thought this was just a theory of what VC stood for and that the ad with the Volkswagen in it was in support of the theory. I wouldn't've been so dumb if someone had included a picture of the box or something. I'd never seen any of that before. The OP's question can be read two ways. Anyway sorry about that and upvoted.

Comment: @hippietrail Serious,who on earth would do pictures over the internet. Total waste of precious transmission bandwidth :))

Comment: Wasted some anyway (-:

Answer (score 5):

It was just renamed — the hardware was identical to other PAL machines being primarily a 6502, a 6561 (the PAL version of the 6560) and a small amount of static RAM.

The C-1540 was similarly rebranded as the VC-1540 in Germany, and the C-1541, which is just a ROM swap of the 1540, was originally the VC-1541.

Comment: Sorry for a late response: Thanks a lot for a great answer (also) to the actual question. (Stupid me, should have realized the 25 vs 30 fps (and, needless to  say the AC/DC transformer, but that I would not anyway consider being part of the VIC/VC)

Answer (score 4):

It was renamed in Germany as VIC pronounced in German is a nasty nasty word. In English it would be written with F a U and a CK.

Comment: ... but only if you're from the South and pronounce V like F. I'm from the North (where we pronounce it like W) and never understood this line of reasoning. See also: the IKEA Gudvik bed :-D

Comment: *"[English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/English#Proper_noun)"* it is (capital "E"). *"[english](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/english#Noun)"* is something [completely different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Now_for_Something_Completely_Different).

Comment: Do you have a source for that claim? As another answer suggests this is an urban myth.

Comment: @MichaelGraf, with the exception of loan words like •Vase•, German •v• is always pronounced like •f•.

Comment: Half of Germany (i.e. the south half) is enough people pronouncing v almost always like f to warrant a company of the size of Commodore to avoid naming the product in a way that will be ambiguous. It is not because you, in your region do not see the issue, that the marketing people of Commodore would not.
@blackjack2 My source. Simply my memory. It was discussed in the press at that time and it was a joke people made constantly (yeah we were immature then). It is likely that someone at Commodore had the forsight to avoid the controversy before it even started.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter Sorry to diapoint you, but the V pronounced F-like is all over Germany, or how do you say Vogel, Vieh or Volkswagen? Wogel, Wieh and Wolkswagen? Don't think so.

Comment: @Raffzahn, I know, I was just responding to Michael Graf in first comment, who said vic would't be pronounced fick in northern Germany, which I doubt as I'm also half Schleswig-Holsteiner. It was only to say that even if it was true, it would be enough to warrant the change.
It's just difficult to explain all these nuances in these comments and my previous comment was confusing (as is probably this one).

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter Let's talk plain: The whole argument of VIC ss Fick is nonsensical. It's a fairy tale story that soulds good and everyone tells with a snicker. It simply lacks any linguistic substance.

Comment: Let's disagree then. I can very well imagine that, looking at the market for which it was intended, that the German marketing department of Commodore would be very cautious. Especially since, according to some sources I just googled, the project was supposed to be named vixen initially, which would be even a worse name for Germany.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I don' visit here often enough, and, since my German is bad, (chose French as 4th language at school 35 years ago; at university wanted to study German but the class was full, so ended up with Japanese). I was also not aware if  e.g. VW is pronounced Wolkswagen in  SH?